# How do I change validation messages from German to English?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, visual-studio-2012

Currently, when I get validation errors in my Project, I have German validation error messages. I would like to have English ones.

They seem to be in `System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll`:

```
moose@pc07:~/Downloads/Team/UpToDatE-Code$ grep -r -i 'Das Feld' *
Binary file ViMuDat/UpToDatE/ViMuDat/ViMuDat/_bin_deployableAssemblies/
                    de/System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll matches
```

What do I have to change to get English validation error messages?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want these validation messages to be English you have to build the project using a Visual Studio which was originally in English. Changing the language to English in an not original English version is not a solution, as validation messages will still be in the former language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the language pack for the .NET Framework.

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Full Language Pack (x86 x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3324)

Comment: After downloading(!) the Readme.htm from the page you've linked: 

"There is no language pack for the English version of this package. If you wish to install the language pack for a different language, please return to the Microsoft Download Center page where you found this download and select a different language."